# How to execute a Python program from the Python shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very very new in Python and I have a doubt.

If I write a program in a text editor (such as Nodepad++), then can I execute it from the Python shell (the one that begin with >>)? What command have I to launch to execute my Python program?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: but the command "python program.py" in the DOS shell or in the Python shell?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using an IDE - there are a lot of free ones out there - or at least IDLE which comes as a part of your python installation.

Comment: @AndreaNobili 'python program.py' is to be run in the DOS shell.

Answer (score 5):

From the Python console, you can run

```
execfile('program.py')
```

where `program.py` is the path to your file.

EDIT:

In Python 3, you'd have to define `execfile` yourself before you could use it. Copy and paste the following.

```
def execfile(path, globals=None, locals=None):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        exec(file.read(), globals, locals)
```

You specifically asked for running it from the Python prompt, but if possible, consider running it from the normal command prompt (DOS, bash, etc.) It's a little easier, and more normal.

Answer (score 3):

- Exit python interpreter/console.
- Edit your program in notepad++ creating **first_program.py** in the same directory where your python.exe is
- start cmd.exe from within exactly the same directory
- type **python first_program.py***

you are done

Comment: The OP wants to do this from the Python console, not cmd.

Comment: Indeed but this shouldn't prevent others from suggesting usage of different approaches.

Comment: By all means. Just recognize you are not answering the OPs exact question "can I execute it from the Python shell". You are suggesting something outside of what (he knew to have) asked.

Comment: @Paul: I agree - but if SO was only for answering questions exactly - there would be no point using it. Often users ask about things that do not cause issues (not this time) but they are unaware of that. In many cases answering exactly solves no problems and provides no benefits. No worries - I've upvoted your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

from within the Python IDLE shell:

File -> Open... -> Select your Python program

When your program has openend select Run -> Run Module or press F5

Answer (score 0):

In the view of mine:
you wrote a program:
test.py

print 'test file'

and you turn to the windows cmd:
you excuted python,and you got this

> > >

then you can just simply:

> > > os.system('python test.py')